# Node PUT request loop error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop, foreach

I asked a similar question last night and hardly got any views and replies. So I'm trying my luck again as I just cant fix this and move on with my project the last two days!

Heres a link to the question yesterday: [Mongoose - No matching document found (ForEach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544076/mongoose-no-matching-document-found-foreach)

Basically, I have a table on my client which have a row id and buttons to update and delete the row. Once an update button is clicked, it sends the row id to the server and executes the PUT request, which works perfectly. The issue comes in from a different row I click, it updates both, the previous row and the new clicked row with the same new data.

I have uploaded a youtube video explaining the issue just in case I havent explained it well here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8sAP3AONYI

Here's my code: (and I have added my github link to the project):

**User.js (model)**

```
local: {
    ...,
    education: [{
        id: String,
        degree: String,
        institute: String,
        dates: String,
        description: String
    }],
    ...
}
```

**router.js**

```
app.put('/put_education/:id', function(req, res) {
    var row_id = req.params.id; //get education id from table row

    //get the current logged in user
    User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('no entry found');
        }

        //match the table row id with the id in users education model
        doc.local.education.forEach(function (education, index) {
            console.log(education.id + "   " + row_id);

            //if rows match, replace the database document with values from client
            if(education.id === row_id){
                doc.local.education[index] = req.body;
                doc.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        res.send("Success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**client javascript**

```
//when edit button on row clicked, change 'save' button to 'update' inside the model
$('#education_body').on('click', '.edit_education', function() {
    var row_id = get_row_id(this);

    $("#education_save_button").hide();
    $("#education_update_button").show();

    //when update button clicked inside the model, call PUT in server
    $('#education_form').on('click', '#education_update_button', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/put_education/' + row_id,
            method: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: $('input[name="education_id"]').val(),
                degree: $('input[name="education_degree"]').val(),
                institute: $('input[name="education_institute"]').val(),
                dates: $('input[name="education_dates"]').val(),
                description: $('textarea[name="education_description"]').val()
            }),
            success: function (response) {
                initialize(); //function to fill in all textfields values from db
                $("#education_saved").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        });

        //change 'update' button back to 'save'
        $("#education_save_button").show();
        $("#education_update_button").hide();
    });
});
```

Please refer to my previous question to see the images of the error and what exactly happens..

*I was thinking of breaking the loop after the id's match but the foreach loop doesnt have a break function, I changed it to a normal for loop but it still gives me the same error. So I dont think breaking the loop is an answer..*

Github: https://github.coventry.ac.uk/salmanfazal01/304CEM-Back-End

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i think your problem comes from the client side. did you check you are sending the right id?

Comment: Yes it does send the right id. 100%. I added a console.log each time an edit button is clicked, and it print the right row, one at a time.

Comment: i think your submit event happens twice i see you video. when you click edit the second time you send 2 requests and not 1. you need to check in your client side code why you fire the event2 times, maybe you add submit event every time you click a row?

Comment: @AmitWagner I'm not sure about that, but I added a print inside the ajax function and the success return as well, they both occur once only per update-click.
Im definitely sure the error comes from the server side, inside the loop as it loops more than once - the previous rows clicked and the new one.

Comment: can you put a console log at the start and see how many times  you get this route ?

Comment: @AmitWagner I did that and it prints the log more times than it should, so you were right the problem comes from the client side. I added the client js code, I have a feeling the approach I took is wrong, but can you help me spot the error please

Comment: In the mean time, I will try separating the two functions (the inner onclick function) and will let you know if it solves the issue.. thanks for your help btw!

Comment: glad it works(:

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by separating the inner click() function from the outer one. Not exactly sure why my initial code didn't work, but this solved it.